# Splitting a Dropdown Field Value to a String, populate 4 fields with array

Tags: javascript, php, arrays, string, gravity-forms-plugin

UPDATE:

Used codementor.io and for the low price of $60+ lol, I got my answer:

```
function the_form(str,varr)
{
console.log(str);
var n=str.split("|");
return n[varr];
//if(varr==0) return n[0]; else return n[1];
}
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
jQuery("#field_1_137").bind("change", function()
{

var selectedValue = jQuery("#field_1_137 option:selected").val();
console.log("selectedvalue:"+selectedValue);
jQuery("#input_1_153").val(the_form(selectedValue,0));
jQuery("#input_1_154").val(the_form(selectedValue,1));
jQuery("#input_1_159").val(the_form(selectedValue,2));
jQuery("#input_1_160").val(the_form(selectedValue,3));

});
});
```

- but hey, feel free to improve on it! Glad I could share. Hope this helps other people : ))

**Original Question below:**

I'm trying to build off of **[this code](https://www.gravityhelp.com/forums/topic/get-value-from-drop-box#position-4)**

Essentially, I have a dropdown, #field_1_149 with values that look like this:

119|135|2|2

I want to split this to a string, and then populate the next four text fields.

Here's what I have so far; however, I keep running into *Uncaught TypeError: str.split is not a function*, which I'm pretty sure means it's not outputting a string...

```
add_filter("gform_pre_render_1", "monitor_dropdown");
function monitor_dropdown($form){

?>
<script type="text/javascript">
function the_form(str, varr) {
  var n = str.split("|");
  if (varr == 1) return n[0];
  else return n[1];
}
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
  jQuery("#field_1_149").bind("change", function() {
    var selectedValue = jQuery("#field_1_149").val();
    jQuery("#input_1_150").val(the_form(selectedValue, 1));
    jQuery("#input_1_152").val(the_form(selectedValue, 2));
    jQuery("#input_1_161").val(the_form(selectedValue, 3));
    jQuery("#input_1_162").val(the_form(selectedValue, 4));

  });
});
</script>
<?php
return $form;
}
```

Comment: str will be undefined, put before split this code, "console.log(str);" without quotes

Comment: works fine here https://jsfiddle.net/ejp7tg03/

Comment: @ÁlvaroTouzón Thank you. That will help!

Comment: @charlietfl I really ppreciate the fiddle! Now I just need to try and get all the split parts in their own respective fields, so each value is unique - but I'm still getting the error.

Comment: `varr-1` would be the index you want probably

Comment: @ÁlvaroTouzón that helped me in that now I can see my str = 0